# Is there any free way to use Phonegap to develop for an iOS device?

Tags: ios, cross-platform, phonegap

I'm trying to figure out how to get PhoneGap to work for cross-platform development. Android is fairly straightforward, but when it comes to iOS, I haven't found a solution that isn't expensive.

I know you can use build.phonegap.com to do it over the cloud, but you need a provisioning profile, which I can't access unless I pay $100 to Apple. I have a free developer account so I had access to my certificates at least, but I can't go further than that unfortunately. I'm just trying to do a homework assignment and I'd rather not pay that much for it.

I'm currently on a Windows 10 laptop, but also I have a Virtual Machine that is running OSX Mojave if that makes a difference.

Or does anyone know if there are any free alternatives that allow me to use HTML/CSS/JS to create apps cross-platform?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no other way to do this other than purchasing a full developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no free or even inexpensive solution for developing applications on iOS.

You need a developer account (99$) and if it is for a serious project, a virtual machine will not be enough to debug.

For your need of make a crossplatform application with HTML/CSS/JS you can see with PWA.

These are not native applications but once installed, the user won't notice anything.

Here is a list of links that can help you :

How to create : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

And apple in there? https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7